# How to find missing values in Regression tree for Veteran Status

Tags: r

I don't know why but I seem to be missing the nodes having to do with veteran status in my regression tree. Perhaps I am missing something? Suggestions welcome!

```
    > str(d1)
    'data.frame':   185390 obs. of  5 variables:
     $ Total.Individual.Income   : int  18899 0 15440 10859 25000 20000 8400 
    0 56002 50012 ...
     $ Race                      : Factor w/ 2 levels "Black, American 
    India, Hispanic, Other",..: 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
     $ Sex                       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 ...
     $ Veteran                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ Educational.Level.Achieved: Factor w/ 2 levels "Associated Degree and Up",..: 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
    > m1 <- rpart(Total.Individual.Income ~ ., data=d1, method="anova")
    > m1
    n= 185390 

    node), split, n, deviance, yval
          * denotes terminal node

    1) root 185390 6.806020e+14 31892.14  
      2) Educational.Level.Achieved=No Degree 130563 1.891821e+14 17617.89 
    *
      3) Educational.Level.Achieved=Associated Degree and Up 54827 
    4.014663e+14 65884.32  
        6) Sex=Female 29910 1.266138e+14 49292.16 *
        7) Sex=Male 24917 2.567340e+14 85801.30 *
```

My goal with this code is to create a regression tree of the predictors above as the respect to total individual income.

Comment: welcome to SO. Please keep in mind that in order to help us help you, it's good idea to provide a reproducible example of your problem and attempted solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that neither is `race`... that may be because neither `race` or `Veteran` are variables really useful at classifying your data, based on the outcome you're looking for (`Total.Individual.Income`).

Anyway, it's difficult to tell in absense of a reproducible example.

See the results to this:

```
require(rpart)
m1 <- rpart(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
> m1
n= 32 

node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 32 1126.04700 20.09062  
  2) cyl>=5 21  198.47240 16.64762  
    4) hp>=192.5 7   28.82857 13.41429 *
    5) hp< 192.5 14   59.87214 18.26429 *
  3) cyl< 5 11  203.38550 26.66364 *
```

Notice that only two variables (`cyl` and `hp`) show as predictors, even though there are 10 variables that can be predictors. Yet, if we do exclude `cyl` and `hp`, we get totally different results:

```
m2 <- rpart(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars[,c(1, 3, 5:11)])
```

then the result changs:

```
> m2
n= 32 

node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 32 1126.04700 20.09062  
  2) wt>=2.3925 25  320.44640 17.58800  
    4) disp>=266.9 14   85.20000 15.10000 *
    5) disp< 266.9 11   38.28727 20.75455 *
  3) wt< 2.3925 7   89.81429 29.02857 *
```

showing us now weight (`wt`) and displacement (`disp`) as predictors.

So nothing is wrong with your code, it seems all you need is to better understand what `rpart` is doing under the hood. `?rpart` may be a good start.